# How to fit implicit polynomial functions to data points (so as to minimize least square distance)?

Tags: curve-fitting

How to fit polynomials of the form $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} y + ....+ a_{0} y^n+ b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+b_{n-2}x^{n-2}y+...=c$, given some data points $(x_i,y_i)$ (so as to minimize sum of least square distances from data points to curve)?

The sources on the internet only seem to suggest the method for polynomial functions of the form $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Why would you want to do regression at all?  You don't seem to have a target variable and an independent variable, nor do you seem to have any randomness!  If all you want to do is solve for the $a_i$ and $b_i$, just use any linear equation solver.  If you don't have exactly as many observations as parameters, the solution is either unidentified, and therefore not unique, or over-identified, in which case picking any $(2n+2)$  observations will give you a unique solution.

Comment: @jbowman What if the number of data points are much greater that $(2n+2)$ and not all them satisfy the polynomial equation ?

Comment: Where is the random term?  Is it y, or added on to c, or...?

Comment: @jbowman What are you talking about? I have a large number of points like: $(1,2),(5,20),.....$. I want a $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} y + ....+ a_{0} y^n+ b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+b_{n-2}x^{n-2}y+...=c$ such that the least square distance of the data points from the curve is minimum.

Comment: That's a legitimate problem, but it's not what people usually mean by "regression."  You therefore need to clarify the text of this post so that you can get appropriate answers.

Comment: You can make a new array of data that stores all the polynomial features. Say x^2*y etc. Then you can do a linear regression on those. This isn't the minimization you asked for, but it does have the right 0 noise case. It avoids solving distance of point to curve.

Comment: @AHusain What do you mean by "0 noise case" ?

Comment: Suppose the data points which obey the true polynomial exactly are $(x_i, y_i)$. Then you're data points you measure will be $(x_i + \epsilon_1 , y_i + \epsilon_2)$. But plugging those in to the LHS will not give $c$ but something close to $c$. The problem I commented minimizes the sum of squares of these errors. However, this is not a priori the same as minimizing the sum of square distances to the curve. Both problems have the common solution if you put all the $\epsilon$ to $0$ though.